# #include <util/Timer.h> returns fatal error: util/Timer.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, file, cmake, header, clion

This is my code. I don't understand why the compiler can't find the  <util/Timer.h> header file.
What did I do wrong?
I have no clue , as  <util/Timer.h> is not created within my project. Do I still have to add it in a cmake file as a path?
I have already checked for misspelling etc.
I get an "no such file or directory warning".

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>


#define protected public
#define private public
#include "ShakingDevice.h"
#undef protected
#undef private

#include <limits.h>
#include "TestConfig.h"
#include <util/Timer.h>

class ShakingDeviceTest : public ::testing::Test {
 public:
  ShakingDevice *s = nullptr;

  virtual void SetUp() {
    //
  }

  virtual void TearDown() {
    //
  }
};

TEST_F(ShakingDeviceTest,testTime) {
  ASSERT_LE(abs(time - expected), 100);
}
```

Comment: Who or what told you to include that file? What is its purpose?

Comment: What platform are you using? Is it case-sensitive? Have you tried `#include <util/timer.h>`?

Answer (score 0):

You should check you cmake or PATH in you platform , the reason why "no such file or directory warning". is system cannot find this file by the paths you give , you should add INCLUDE  into your cmake file so that the system will know where to find this head file .

Answer (score 0):

I used #include"chrono" instead and now it works.
I looked up some libraries here on stackoverflow, but it was the wrong one.